# UISplitViewController presentsWithGesture = YES not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

in my `AppDelegate` in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` I instantiate an `UISplitViewController` with the following code:

```
PopMenuViewController *menuVC = [[PopMenuViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
    UINavigationController *menuNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:menuVC];

PopMenuDetailViewController *detailVC = [[PopMenuDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PopMenuDetailViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *detailNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:detailVC];

menuVC.detailViewController = detailVC;

splitViewController = [[UISplitViewController alloc] init];
splitViewController.viewControllers = @[menuNavController, detailNavController];
splitViewController.presentsWithGesture = YES;
splitViewController.delegate = self;
self.window.rootViewController = splitViewController;
```

But, in Portrait mode, when I slide on the screen (from left to right) the left view controller doesn't appear (but the `presentsWithGesture` is set to `YES`).

I run the project on Simulator and a physical device with iOS 7.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

On iOS 7, you must implement this delegate method for your `UISplitViewController` in order for the gesture to work:

```
-(void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController*)splitController willHideViewController:(UIViewController*)viewController withBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem*)barButtonItem forPopoverController:(UIPopoverController*)popoverController
```

**EDIT:** you don't need to actually do anything inside the method, it just needs to be implemented.